# Creating oracle Database instace

Tags: oracle-11g, impdp

We need to create a oracle database instance similar to customer environment. What are all the parameters needs to be considered other than similar version of software.

Like Character set, Multibyte Or Single Byte and other Database, Instance, Session level parameters which are to be considered.

1. What happen if a Dump Successfully imported into a Database instance with different NLS parameters, Will it be having any Side effects?
2. Is there a standard way of creating a replica of customer instance in our local?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 'takes care' of the conversion between different NLS settings. As long as both NLS settings can store the same characters the there should be no problem. It is the same as the difference between the database and a client.

If for example the database of the customer is in UTF-8 and you create a database in ISO8859-P1 then you will loose (some) characters with accents and from non-western alphabets. The other way around gives no problem.

Comment: Is there a standard way of creating a replica of customer instance in our local?

Comment: I do not know of any standard way. I did it in the past by creating an `spfile.ora` based on a minimal `init.ora` for the new instance and then clone the 'source' database with RMAN. With `impdp` you first need to create an 'empty' database.

Comment: Yes, I want to use IMPDP. While Creating EMPTY Database what are all NLS Parameters to be same. Since, We found 20 properties when we query (select * from nls_database_parameters;).

Comment: If I remember well the only `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` are important. Normally you should not have (user) data that is defined as `NCHAR` so `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` should have no influence on the data that you import.